# Display the count of field in a view

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that look like this

```
ID      NIP       SHIFT DATE
289305  01000267    M   2015-12-01 00:00:00.000
289306  01000267    P   2015-12-01 00:00:00.000
289307  01000267    S   2015-12-01 00:00:00.000
289127  01020358    M   2015-12-01 00:00:00.000
289128  01020358    P   2015-12-01 00:00:00.000
289129  01020358    S   2015-12-01 00:00:00.000
284686  01020386    P   2015-12-01 00:00:00.000
290925  01030389    F   2015-12-01 00:00:00.000
290685  01030390    F   2015-12-01 00:00:00.000
289485  01000306    P   2015-12-01 00:00:00.000
283069  01030391    P   2015-12-01 00:00:00.000
290715  01030392    M   2015-12-01 00:00:00.000
290716  01030392    P   2015-12-01 00:00:00.000
290717  01030392    S   2015-12-01 00:00:00.000
289605  01040399    M   2015-12-01 00:00:00.000
289606  01040399    P   2015-12-01 00:00:00.000
289607  01040399    S   2015-12-01 00:00:00.000
281490  01050401    M   2015-12-01 00:00:00.000
281488  01050401    P   2015-12-01 00:00:00.000
281489  01050401    S   2015-12-01 00:00:00.000
281953  01060545    P   2015-12-01 00:00:00.000
289217  01060549    M   2015-12-01 00:00:00.000
289218  01060549    P   2015-12-01 00:00:00.000
289219  01060549    S   2015-12-01 00:00:00.000
289515  01060671    M   2015-12-01 00:00:00.000
289516  01060671    P   2015-12-01 00:00:00.000
289517  01060671    S   2015-12-01 00:00:00.000
289785  01110963    M   2015-12-01 00:00:00.000
289786  01110963    P   2015-12-01 00:00:00.000
289787  01110963    S   2015-12-01 00:00:00.000
290415  01120632    M   2015-12-01 00:00:00.000
290416  01120632    P   2015-12-01 00:00:00.000
290417  01120632    S   2015-12-01 00:00:00.000
290235  01120964    M   2015-12-01 00:00:00.000
290236  01120964    P   2015-12-01 00:00:00.000
290237  01120964    S   2015-12-01 00:00:00.000
289037  01130654    M   2015-12-01 00:00:00.000
289038  01130654    P   2015-12-01 00:00:00.000
289039  01130654    S   2015-12-01 00:00:00.000
290595  01130655    M   2015-12-01 00:00:00.000
290596  01130655    P   2015-12-01 00:00:00.000
290597  01130655    S   2015-12-01 00:00:00.000
291045  01130658    M   2015-12-01 00:00:00.000
291046  01130658    P   2015-12-01 00:00:00.000
291047  01130658    S   2015-12-01 00:00:00.000
291135  01131020    M   2015-12-01 00:00:00.000
291136  01131020    P   2015-12-01 00:00:00.000
291137  01131020    S   2015-12-01 00:00:00.000
290835  01141011    M   2015-12-01 00:00:00.000
290836  01141011    P   2015-12-01 00:00:00.000
290837  01141011    S   2015-12-01 00:00:00.000
...
```

Now, I want to display a view that something like this:

```
NIP         P   S   M   C   D   I   K   L   R
03950086    21  0   0   3   0   0   0   7   0
03070445    3   11  9   0   0   0   0   8   0
32041041    7   9   6   6   0   0   0   6   0
32980188    25  0   0   0   0   0   0   6   0
03000255    6   12  6   0   0   0   0   7   0
03020366    8   9   6   0   0   0   0   8   0
30000237    24  0   0   0   0   0   0   7   0
32920073    11  10  0   0   0   2   0   8   0
03020365    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
03140836    8   10  6   0   0   0   0   7   0
01030391    25  0   0   0   0   0   0   6   0
32151002    8   6   8   0   0   0   0   9   0
32150929    5   9   9   0   0   0   0   8   0
03000294    7   10  6   0   0   0   0   8   0
03010339    6   9   8   0   0   0   0   8   0
03950115    22  0   0   0   0   1   0   8   0
03091087    6   10  7   0   0   0   0   8   0
03100508    2   10  6   6   0   0   0   7   0
32100618    23  0   1   0   0   0   0   8   0
03140474    8   6   9   0   0   0   0   8   0
32090500    21  0   3   0   0   0   0   10  0
03060415    4   11  8   3   0   0   0   5   0
03020369    22  0   0   2   0   0   0   7   0
03950096    20  3   0   0   0   0   0   8   0
03130639    9   7   6   0   0   0   0   9   0
03141056    4   9   9   0   0   0   0   9   0
01000306    31  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
03100607    7   7   8   0   1   0   0   8   0
03141050    7   8   8   0   0   0   0   8   0
03080475    4   8   7   6   0   0   0   6   0
50140009    15  25  15  0   0   0   0   6   0
31950104    10  11  5   0   0   0   0   5   0
03041026    11  12  0   0   2   0   0   6   0
32151118    11  8   2   0   0   0   2   8   0
05150750    18  3   3   0   0   0   0   7   0
03000261    13  11  0   0   0   0   0   7   0
07151125    13  0   0   0   0   0   0   4   0
03100509    4   7   7   4   0   0   0   9   0
01060548    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
03060417    5   10  8   0   0   0   0   8   0
32151124    24  0   0   0   0   0   0   7   0
03080476    5   8   9   3   0   0   0   6   0
11110677    6   16  2   0   0   0   0   7   0
03970169    0   0   0   31  0   0   0   0   0
32890042    18  0   0   6   0   0   0   7   0
03990229    7   0   15  0   0   0   0   9   0
32890043    24  0   0   5   0   0   0   2   0
01970201    25  0   0   0   0   0   0   6   0
03140007    7   8   8   0   1   0   0   7   0
32150930    11  5   6   0   0   0   0   9   0
```

where P,S,M, etc, is the count number, and date is between `startdate` and `enddate`, this is my attempt so far

```
SELECT        
                             (SELECT        COUNT(shift) AS Expr1
                               FROM            dbo.JadwalKerja
                               WHERE        (nip = dbo.JadwalDinas_DaftarKaryawan.NIP) AND (shift = 'B' OR
                                                         shift = 'E' OR
                                                         shift = 'F' OR
                                                         shift = 'G' OR
                                                         shift = 'H' OR
                                                         shift = 'J' OR
                                                         shift = 'P') AND (date >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-12-01 00:00:00', 102)) AND (date <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-12-31 00:00:00', 102))) AS P,
                             (SELECT        COUNT(shift) AS Expr1
                               FROM            dbo.JadwalKerja AS JadwalKerja_8
                               WHERE        (nip = dbo.JadwalDinas_DaftarKaryawan.NIP) AND (shift = 'B' OR
                                                         shift = 'N' OR
                                                         shift = 'O' OR
                                                         shift = 'S' OR
                                                         shift = 'T') AND (date >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-12-01 00:00:00', 102)) AND (date <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-12-31 00:00:00', 102))) AS S,
                             (SELECT        COUNT(shift) AS Expr1
                               FROM            dbo.JadwalKerja AS JadwalKerja_7
                               WHERE        (nip = dbo.JadwalDinas_DaftarKaryawan.NIP) AND (shift = 'B' OR
                                                         shift = 'M' OR
                                                         shift = 'Q') AND (date >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-12-01 00:00:00', 102)) AND (date <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-12-31 00:00:00', 102))) AS M,
                             (SELECT        COUNT(shift) AS Expr1
                               FROM            dbo.JadwalKerja AS JadwalKerja_6
                               WHERE        (nip = dbo.JadwalDinas_DaftarKaryawan.NIP) AND (shift = 'C') AND (date >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-12-01 00:00:00', 102)) AND (date <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-12-31 00:00:00', 102))) AS C,
                             (SELECT        COUNT(shift) AS Expr1
                               FROM            dbo.JadwalKerja AS JadwalKerja_5
                               WHERE        (nip = dbo.JadwalDinas_DaftarKaryawan.NIP) AND (shift = 'D') AND (date >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-12-01 00:00:00', 102)) AND (date <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-12-31 00:00:00', 102))) AS D,
                             (SELECT        COUNT(shift) AS Expr1
                               FROM            dbo.JadwalKerja AS JadwalKerja_4
                               WHERE        (nip = dbo.JadwalDinas_DaftarKaryawan.NIP) AND (shift = 'I') AND (date >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-12-01 00:00:00', 102)) AND (date <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-12-31 00:00:00', 102))) AS I,
                             (SELECT        COUNT(shift) AS Expr1
                               FROM            dbo.JadwalKerja AS JadwalKerja_3
                               WHERE        (nip = dbo.JadwalDinas_DaftarKaryawan.NIP) AND (shift = 'K') AND (date >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-12-01 00:00:00', 102)) AND (date <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-12-31 00:00:00', 102))) AS K,
                             (SELECT        COUNT(shift) AS Expr1
                               FROM            dbo.JadwalKerja AS JadwalKerja_2
                               WHERE        (nip = dbo.JadwalDinas_DaftarKaryawan.NIP) AND (shift = 'L') AND (date >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-12-01 00:00:00', 102)) AND (date <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-12-31 00:00:00', 102))) AS L,
                             (SELECT        COUNT(shift) AS Expr1
                               FROM            dbo.JadwalKerja AS JadwalKerja_1
                               WHERE        (nip = dbo.JadwalDinas_DaftarKaryawan.NIP) AND (shift = 'R') AND (date >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-12-01 00:00:00', 102)) AND (date <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-12-31 00:00:00', 102))) 
                         AS R
FROM            dbo.JadwalDinas_DaftarKaryawan
ORDER BY Nama
```

I am not sure if this is the correct way to do this.

I use SQL server 2000, so  [`PIVOT`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) isn't an option.

Comment: So, in your result table, you are combining shifts? The only obvious chanegs I see: use `IN ('A', 'B', ...)` instead of OR. A temporary table (or nested table) may help too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first you'd choose indentation to make the whole query more easily readable:

```
SELECT        
  (
    SELECT COUNT(shift) AS Expr1
    FROM dbo.JadwalKerja
    WHERE
      (nip = dbo.JadwalDinas_DaftarKaryawan.NIP)
      AND (
        shift = 'B' OR
        shift = 'E' OR
        shift = 'F' OR
        shift = 'G' OR
        shift = 'H' OR
        shift = 'J' OR
        shift = 'P'
      )
      AND (date >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-12-01 00:00:00', 102))
      AND (date <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-12-31 00:00:00', 102))
  ) AS P,
  (
    SELECT COUNT(shift) AS Expr1
    FROM dbo.JadwalKerja AS JadwalKerja_8
    WHERE
      (nip = dbo.JadwalDinas_DaftarKaryawan.NIP)
      AND (
        shift = 'B' OR
        shift = 'N' OR
        shift = 'O' OR
        shift = 'S' OR
        shift = 'T'
      )
      AND (date >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-12-01 00:00:00', 102))
      AND (date <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-12-31 00:00:00', 102))
  ) AS S,
  (
    SELECT COUNT(shift) AS Expr1
    FROM dbo.JadwalKerja AS JadwalKerja_7
    WHERE
      (nip = dbo.JadwalDinas_DaftarKaryawan.NIP)
      AND (
        shift = 'B' OR
        shift = 'M' OR
        shift = 'Q'
      )
      AND (date >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-12-01 00:00:00', 102))
      AND (date <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-12-31 00:00:00', 102))
  ) AS M,
  (
    SELECT COUNT(shift) AS Expr1
    FROM dbo.JadwalKerja AS JadwalKerja_6
    WHERE
      (nip = dbo.JadwalDinas_DaftarKaryawan.NIP)
      AND (shift = 'C')
      AND (date >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-12-01 00:00:00', 102))
      AND (date <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-12-31 00:00:00', 102))
  ) AS C,
  (
    SELECT COUNT(shift) AS Expr1
    FROM dbo.JadwalKerja AS JadwalKerja_5
    WHERE
      (nip = dbo.JadwalDinas_DaftarKaryawan.NIP)
      AND (shift = 'D')
      AND (date >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-12-01 00:00:00', 102))
      AND (date <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-12-31 00:00:00', 102))
  ) AS D,
  (
    SELECT COUNT(shift) AS Expr1
    FROM dbo.JadwalKerja AS JadwalKerja_4
    WHERE
      (nip = dbo.JadwalDinas_DaftarKaryawan.NIP)
      AND (shift = 'I')
      AND (date >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-12-01 00:00:00', 102))
      AND (date <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-12-31 00:00:00', 102))
  ) AS I,
  (
    SELECT COUNT(shift) AS Expr1
    FROM dbo.JadwalKerja AS JadwalKerja_3
    WHERE
      (nip = dbo.JadwalDinas_DaftarKaryawan.NIP)
      AND (shift = 'K')
      AND (date >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-12-01 00:00:00', 102))
      AND (date <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-12-31 00:00:00', 102))
  ) AS K,
  (
    SELECT COUNT(shift) AS Expr1
    FROM dbo.JadwalKerja AS JadwalKerja_2
    WHERE
      (nip = dbo.JadwalDinas_DaftarKaryawan.NIP)
      AND (shift = 'L')
      AND (date >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-12-01 00:00:00', 102))
      AND (date <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-12-31 00:00:00', 102))
  ) AS L,
  (
    SELECT COUNT(shift) AS Expr1
    FROM dbo.JadwalKerja AS JadwalKerja_1
    WHERE
      (nip = dbo.JadwalDinas_DaftarKaryawan.NIP)
      AND (shift = 'R')
      AND (date >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-12-01 00:00:00', 102))
      AND (date <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-12-31 00:00:00', 102))
  ) AS R
FROM dbo.JadwalDinas_DaftarKaryawan
ORDER BY Nama
```

That's said, its expression may be simplified in several ways.

There is no need of (furthermore unused) aliases like `AS Expr1` or `AS JadwalKerja_N`, and they can be dropped.

All the OR-ed sets of conditions can be more simply expressed using IN, so `AND (shift = 'A' OR ... OR shift = 'Z')` becomes `AND shift IN ('A', ..., 'Z')`.

The way you expressed the date conditions (CONVERT style = 102) leads to deduct that the `date` field original content is currently of the form `yyyy.mm.dd`:

```
AND (date >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-12-01 00:00:00', 102))
AND (date <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-12-31 00:00:00', 102))
```

So why to use another style for the start/end date? You can merely write (also noting that the 102 style doesn't takes care of hours, and that the parenthesis are not needed):

```
AND date >= '2015.12.01'
AND date >= '2015.12.31'
```

More over, this can be expressed within a unique condition, like this:

```
AND date BETWEEN '2015.12.01' AND '2015.12.31'
```

With all the changes suggested above, you get a dramatically reduced query:

```
SELECT        
  (
    SELECT COUNT(shift) FROM dbo.JadwalKerja
    WHERE (nip = dbo.JadwalDinas_DaftarKaryawan.NIP)
      AND shift IN ('B', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'P')
      AND date BETWEEN '2015.12.01' AND '2015.12.31'
  ) AS P,
  (
    SELECT COUNT(shift) FROM dbo.JadwalKerja
    WHERE (nip = dbo.JadwalDinas_DaftarKaryawan.NIP)
      AND shift IN ('B', 'N', 'O', 'S', 'T')
      AND date BETWEEN '2015.12.01' AND '2015.12.31'
  ) AS S,
  (
    SELECT COUNT(shift) FROM dbo.JadwalKerja
    WHERE (nip = dbo.JadwalDinas_DaftarKaryawan.NIP)
      AND shift IN ('B', 'M', 'Q')
      AND date BETWEEN '2015.12.01' AND '2015.12.31'
  ) AS M,
  (
    SELECT COUNT(shift) FROM dbo.JadwalKerja
    WHERE (nip = dbo.JadwalDinas_DaftarKaryawan.NIP)
      AND shift = 'C'
      AND date BETWEEN '2015.12.01' AND '2015.12.31'
  ) AS C,
  (
    SELECT COUNT(shift) FROM dbo.JadwalKerja
    WHERE (nip = dbo.JadwalDinas_DaftarKaryawan.NIP)
      AND shift = 'D'
      AND date BETWEEN '2015.12.01' AND '2015.12.31'
  ) AS D,
  (
    SELECT COUNT(shift) FROM dbo.JadwalKerja
    WHERE (nip = dbo.JadwalDinas_DaftarKaryawan.NIP)
      AND shift = 'I'
      AND date BETWEEN '2015.12.01' AND '2015.12.31'
  ) AS I,
  (
    SELECT COUNT(shift) FROM dbo.JadwalKerja
    WHERE (nip = dbo.JadwalDinas_DaftarKaryawan.NIP)
      AND shift = 'K'
      AND date BETWEEN '2015.12.01' AND '2015.12.31'
  ) AS K,
  (
    SELECT COUNT(shift) FROM dbo.JadwalKerja
    WHERE (nip = dbo.JadwalDinas_DaftarKaryawan.NIP)
      AND shift = 'L'
      AND date BETWEEN '2015.12.01' AND '2015.12.31'
  ) AS L,
  (
    SELECT COUNT(shift) FROM dbo.JadwalKerja
    WHERE (nip = dbo.JadwalDinas_DaftarKaryawan.NIP)
      AND shift = 'R'
      AND date BETWEEN '2015.12.01' AND '2015.12.31'
  ) AS R
FROM dbo.JadwalDinas_DaftarKaryawan
ORDER BY Nama
```

Going further, you might consider using a two-steps query, where the first one would be creating a temp table from:

```
SELECT shift, nip, date
FROM dbo.JadwalKerja
WHERE date BETWEEN '2015.12.01' AND '2015.12.31'
```

then using the temp table in place of dbo.JadwalKerja in the second step, where the date condition can be omitted.

*Note 1:  this alternate way may improve performance or not, depending on the distribution of the involved contents in the table.

Note 2: since I'm not familiar with SQL Server I didn't specify which way could be used: might be using `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` syntax, or `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE` then `LOAD DATA INFILE`.*

On the other hand, unless I'm missing something, I don't see how the `ORDER BY Nama` can make sense here.